# Issues with if, elif and len(x)

Tags: python

I'm attempting to code myself a login and registration script and I've got an issue with my username definition. I can run the code without one of my validation methods but with it in, the code always seems to break.

```
    usernameloop = 1
    while usernameloop == 1:
        username = input("Please input your desired username.")
        if len(username) >> 20:
            print("Unable to choose that username, you need to have less than 20 characters in your username.")
        elif len(username) >= 4 and len(username) <= 20:
            print("Username Selected. Your username is:", username)
            time.sleep(1)
            usernameloop = 0
            break

# This is the problematic statement. It doesn't work if this is in and always goes to this statement even if the validation should be correct.

        elif len(username) << 4: 
            print("Unable to choose that username, you need 3 or more characters in your username.")
        else:
            print("An Unknown Error Occurred, contact x with the screenshot of the conversation history.")
            time.sleep(10)
            exit()
```

Does anyone know why its not working, I have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: You are using `>>` and `<<` where you want `>` and `<`.

Comment: `len(username) >> 20` will be 0 for strings with fewer than 2**20 characters; `len(username) << 4` will be nonzero (and thus true) for any non-empty string.

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Use single '<' or '>' in place of '<<' or '>>' and it will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

`>` is a [Comparison Operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm)

`>>` is a [bitwise oprator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)